# Binding to a random free port (as with port 0) in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

In Bash only, how can I retrieve two open port numbers that are guaranteed to be available, as is done in other languages (Perl or Python) by binding to port 0? My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I've seen perl and python examples, but nothing that works without using a separate language.

My end goal is to replace the following unreliable script, so I can assign the results to variables and use them later in my script

```
count=0;
for i in {11212..12655}
do
    netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-$i} -q ;
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        aLen=${#PORTS[@]};
        #echo $i:$?
        if [ $aLen -lt 2 ]; then
            PORTS[$count]=$i;
            ((count++));
        else
            break;
        fi;
    fi;
done
PORTs1="${PORTS[0]}";
PORTs2="${PORTS[1]}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up utilizing Python to get what I needed.

```
PORT1=$(python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()');
PORT2=$(python -c 'import socket; s=socket.socket(); s.bind(("", 0)); print(s.getsockname()[1]); s.close()');
```

Answer (score 1):

Inasmuch as your goal is to assign two port numbers, which are guaranteed to be free, to `PORTs1` and `PORTs2` variables, such that they can be bound to at a later point in time, *this is inherently impossible*.

The entire reason binding to port 0 works is that it lets the operating system choose a port that is immediately available *at the time of the operation itself*. If you choose the port number *before* you open it, then you've created a window in which another process can bind to the port. By contrast, if you bind to the port before you start the program that ultimately needs to own the listening socket, it's no longer free.

---

Passing a file descriptor pre-bound to a port -- rather than passing a port number to later bind to -- is possible (though not using shell-built-in functionality that's guaranteed to be present in bash), but it's going to require rewriting the program you're invoking; and if you're going to do that, you might as well rewrite that program to ask the OS to randomly select its port numbers and write them out in a usable format itself.

Comment: the point is to use the variables later in the same script only... within milliseconds of applying the values to the variables, and the script will only be run by one person, at one time

Comment: There's no guarantee that your script is the only thing on your machine trying to bind to port 0: _Lots_ of software uses that same technique. And the whole question is premised on trying to replace unreliable software with something reliable. Using techniques that are known to have race conditions is not a solid foundation on which to build reliable systems.